# Why does React randomly (so it seems) reload cached images?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, jsx

So I've been trying to work on a simple website using React. The basic layout I want to implement at the moment is that each page has (top to bottom): image, navbar and contents. I put the image and navbar into a Header component. The idea is that whenever user selects another page from navbar the image at the top changes corresponding to that page (Header receives 'banner' prop, which indicates the name of the image file to be switched to). 
For some reason, when I switch between pages, sometimes React decides to reload the image component, even though it's been cached.

I was worried that each image is loaded separately upon the switch to a corresponding page, so I explicitly added some code to make all images load right away, and I can verify that it works on the network tab in dev. tools (when I load main page, network detects requests to all images with **200** response). Once that's done the weird things start happening. Whenever I switch to another page one of the two things randomly happen:

1. The image is switched instantly (as expected) and it does NOT make any network requests.
2. The page "re-renders" its components as if it has to re-load the header image, aka for a millisecond the contents of the page look as (tiny empty space, navbar, contents) and then it goes back to (image, navbar, contents) which creates an ugly jerky effect. Whenever this happens, the network tab in dev. tools catches a request to new image with **304** response.

Now, 304 means the requested resource hasn't been modified. But if it hasn't been modified (aka it's cached), then:

1. Why does React need to redraw it as if it reloads the resource, even though sometimes it can redraw right away?
2. Why doesn't it send requests to fetch resources consistently? Is there some rule as to when it checks if the item is cached and when it doesn't?

Here's a bit of code for Header component:

```
class Header extends React.Component {

    static images_loaded = false;

    constructor(props) {
        super();

        this.state = {
            banner: props.banner,
            map: {}
        }
}

    componentDidMount() {
        const map = {};
        if (!Header.images_loaded) {   // trying to load once per all Header instances
            ['main_page', 'about_me', 'bits', 'portfolio', 'resume', 'thoughts'].forEach((name) => {
                const img = new Image();
                img.src = require('./banners/' + name + '.png');
            });

            Header.images_loaded = true;

        }
    }

    render() {
      return ( 
            <div>
            <img src={require('./banners/' + this.state.banner + '.png')} /> 
                <div>
                    <Navbar bg="dark" variant="dark" expand="lg" sticky="top">
                       {'Navbar contents'}
                    </Navbar>
                </div>
            </div>
          );
        }
  }

  export default Header;
```

Expected behaviour: 
Switching between pages causes images switch instantly, without reloads.

Actual behaviour:
Switching between pages causes random "re-fetches" and image re-renders.

Am I misunderstanding how cache works or maybe React workflow? I'm really confused about what's happening and why.
Would appreciate someone's help a lot, thank you.

UPD: the images size varies within 1.45-3.02 Mb

Comment: It would be nice to see an example in codesandbox.io. You don't `!Header.images_loaded` images will loaded once by componentDidMount. You don't need state in your component since you only use props.

Comment: Define what "Switching pages" means....react router pages or complete new page load

Comment: @charlietfl Yeah, by pages I mean react-router "pages". And I'm using Link instead of regular href to switch between them, so I don't think it's an issue of reloading the page over and over. Plus, as I mentioned, sometimes the behaviour is as expected, but there seems to be no pattern in when that happens and when it doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

Using create-react-app, you can get the desired result by importing the files outside of the render function. If the image is less than 10,000 bytes, it returns the data uri instead of the path to reduce the number of requests to the server.

[Adding images in Create React App](https://facebook.github.io/create-react-app/docs/adding-images-fonts-and-files)

If you are using something like react-router, you should be able to change the image src based on the path like this:

```
import React from "react";
import { withRouter } from "react-router";
import red from "./banners/red.png";
import blue from "./banners/blue.png";
import green from "./banners/green.png";

const colorMap = {
  "/": red,
  "/about/": blue,
  "/users/": green
};

const Header = props => {
  console.log(props, colorMap[props.location.pathname]);
  return (
    <div>
      <img
        alt=""
        src={colorMap[props.location.pathname]}
        style={{ height: "200px", width: "200px" }}
      />
    </div>
  );
};

export default withRouter(Header);
```

For your current implementation, you could instead use `this.props.banner` instead of `this.state.banner`. Assigning state to props is generally considered an anti-pattern because it duplicates data and makes the source of truth confusing.

Comment: I tried this, but then realized my images are actually way above 10000 bytes in size (varying within 1.45-3.02 Mb), so this approach didn't work. The create-react-app doc says that if the files are right size, webpack automatically transforms the data into Data URI and embeds it into the module. Is there a way to transform larger resource files into Data URL's or does that sound like a bad idea?

Comment: That doesn't sound bad at all. There are image compression tools if you search around. They aren't guaranteed to get you down to a certain size of image and they might make the image less high resolution.